# Break out of for loop of Promises

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, asynchronous, break

I come to you with a question related to for loops and promises.

So to explain the situation: I have a `for` loop that will run a number of times. This loop uses `fetch` to post to an API.
Depending on what comes back as a response from each POST request, I want to break the loop if a certain condition is met.

So for example, if the loop is set to run 5 times but on the 3rd iteration the break condition is met, I do not want to execute the rest of it, therefore preventing the other POST requests from executing.

I think you will understand the issue once you see the code:

```
send: function () {
    const procedure = 'someProcedure';
    const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
    for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        const obj = {
            procedure: procedure,
            saunaScheduleId: fields[i].dataset.id,
            guestMediumHID: '',
            guestMediumNumber: fields[i].innerHTML
        };
        fetch(EventBooking.variables.api, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: 'cors',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }),
            body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data[0].resultCode == 3) {
                console.log(obj.guestMediumNumber + ' booked this event.');
                return;
            }
            else if(data[0].resultCode == 0 && i == fields.length - 1) {
                console.log('Booking completed successfully!');
                EventBooking.booking.clear();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From what I read, It has to do with the `for` loop somehow being done way ahead of the API calls.
The second if in the loop seems to be doing good once all the calls have been executed successfully it shows one message for all of them.

How would you go about handling this kind of situation?

Thank you for your help.
Cheers!

Comment: You'll want to use `async`/`await`. The alternative would be a recursive approach instead of the loop.

Comment: Simply add a condition in the loop control flow and make that condition be met by setting a variable.

Comment: You're right, that would just run the `fetch` calls independently. If you want the the decision for one call to depend on the response from the previous call then the calls need to run in series. Take a look at the async library's `series` method, where you can use the response from call N-1 at step N, and use the fact that you can call `callback(something_true, _)` to stop the series.  https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#series --or indeed `async/await` as @Bergi suggests, if your browser JS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive

```
send: function () {
    const procedure = 'someProcedure';
    const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
    const fetching = index => {
        if (index >= fields.length) return;
        const obj = {
            procedure: procedure,
            saunaScheduleId: fields[index].dataset.id,
            guestMediumHID: '',
            guestMediumNumber: fields[index].innerHTML
        };
        fetch(EventBooking.variables.api, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: 'cors',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }),
            body: JSON.stringify(obj)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data[0].resultCode == 3) {
                console.log(obj.guestMediumNumber + ' booked this event.');
                return;
            }
            else if(data[0].resultCode == 0 && index == fields.length - 1) {
                console.log('Booking completed successfully!');
                EventBooking.booking.clear();
            }
            fetching(index + 1);
        });
    };
    fetching(0);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the respective promises so that the caller of each function can wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go for this:

Seems clean and works.

```
send: async function () {
        const procedure = 'SaveSaunaEventBooking';
        const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
        for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            const obj = {
                procedure: procedure,
                saunaScheduleId: fields[i].dataset.id,
                guestMediumHID: '',
                guestMediumNumber: fields[i].innerHTML
            };
            let response = await fetch(EventBooking.variables.api, {
                method: "POST",
                mode: 'cors',
                redirect: 'follow',
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }),
                body: JSON.stringify(obj)
            })
            let data = await response.json();
            if (data[0].resultCode == 3) {
                console.log(obj.guestMediumNumber + ' booked this event.');
                return;
            }
            else if (data[0].resultCode == 0 && i == fields.length - 1) {
                console.log('Booking completed successfully!');
                EventBooking.booking.clear();
            }

        }
```

Thanks for all your ideas and help! :)